# How can I use Java reflection to invoke a method on a reference variable?

Tags: java, variables, reflection, reference, invoke

Class `X` is being used inside class `Y`. Class `X` has a function `xMethod` that is not used inside class `Y`.
Can I use reflection on Class `Y` to invoke the `xMethod` on `Y`'s `xInternalVar`?How?

```
class X  {
    void xMethod (){ 
    //some code
}

class Y {
    X xInternalVar = new X();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you've just got two steps here:

1. Fetch the value of `xIntervalVar` - use [`Class.getDeclaredField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29) to get at the relevant field in `Y`, then get the value of it for the relevant *instance* of `Y`
2. Call `xMethod` on the instance of `X` - use [`Class.getDeclaredMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to get at the relevant method in `X`, then invoke the method using the value returned by step 1.